# Rally SDK 2.00 p2 Adding several Checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, rally

I am trying to add Checkboxes for a Rally Report version 2.00p2.

I defined severals place holders for the filter (releaseFilter and stateFilter)
and Adding the checkboxes at the body of the onReady function at the end.

However, Instead of 5 different checkbox I get 1 and on top of the Release filter.
Sorry But I couldn't add an Image.

```
Rally.onReady(function() {

      Ext.define('CustomApp', {
            extend: 'Rally.app.App',
            componentCls: 'app',


        autoScroll: 'true',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    itemId: 'releaseFilter',
                    style: {
                        margin: '5px'
                        }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    itemId: 'stateFilter',
                    style: {
                        margin: '5px'
                        }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    itemId: 'grid',
                    style: {
                        margin: '10px',
                        }
                },
                // SOME CODE
        ],
            launch: function() {
                Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
                    type: 'UserStory',
                    success: function(model) {
                        this.grid = this.add({
                            xtype: 'rallygrid',
                            model: model,
                            columnCfgs: [
                                'FormattedID',
                                'Release',
                                'Iteration',
                                'PlanEstimate',
                                'PlanDevEstDays',
                                'PlanQAEstDays'
                            ],
                            storeConfig: {
                                filters: [
                                    {
                                        property: 'ScheduleState',
                                        operator: '=',
                                        value: 'Accepted'
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        });
                    this.down('#releaseFilter').add(
                    {
            xtype: 'rallyreleasecombobox'                           
        }
                );

                this.down('#stateFilter').add([{
                        xtype: 'menucheckitem',
                                                    text: 'Backlog',
                                                    floating: 'false'
                    },{
                        xtype: 'menucheckitem',
                                                    text: 'Defined'
                    },{
                        xtype: 'menucheckitem',
                                                    text: 'In-Progress'
                    },{
                        xtype: 'menucheckitem',
                                                    text: 'Completed'
                    },{
                        xtype: 'menucheckitem',
                                                    text: 'Accepted'
                    }]
                );


                    },
                    scope: this
                });
            }
       });


        Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
            name: 'Grid Example'
        });
    });
```

The original Entry in your javadoc is:

```
Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
width: 100,
height: 110,
floating: false,  // usually you want this set to True (default)
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),  // usually rendered by it's containing component
items: [{
    xtype: 'menucheckitem',
    text: 'select all'
 },{
    xtype: 'menucheckitem',
    text: 'select specific',
 },{
    iconCls: 'add16',
    text: 'icon item'
 },{
    text: 'regular item'
 }]
});
```

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: You can upload a screenshot to http://imgur.com, and post the direct URL. So are the checkboxes stacked? Or is only the first one defined visible?

Comment: Only the first one defined with a real checkbox, the others are shown only by label without a checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `menucheckitem`, use a standard Ext checkbox. Like this:

```
this.down('#stateFilter').add([{
        xtype: 'checkbox',
        fieldLabel: 'Backlog'
    },
    ...
]);
```

Be sure change it from `text` to `fieldLabel`